# Does the Google Plugin for Eclipse require the J2EE web project plugin?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I was wondering, does the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/gwt) includes in its dependencies the Java EE perspective ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory. You can download basic Java Edition of Eclipse and install GPE plugin.

Following are sufficient to write GWT program.

1. [Kepler - Eclipse JAVA IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/keplerr)
2. [GPE Plugin for Kepler](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3)

**Note -**

1. [GPE FAQ](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq#gwt_in_eclipse_for_java_ee)
2. [Maven and GPE](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary.
You can use this tutorial to create your first project: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/create.html

Here you can find all documentation you need to develop gwt application.